# Does functions occupy more memory for each instance of the same object?

Tags: java, class, object, memory, memory-management

Imagine this extreme situation:

A class `City` with 10 variables, but 1000 lines of functions and logic that operates these variables.

```
Class Person {    
    // 10 variables
    int age = 20;
    int height = 180;
    String name = "Name";
    .
    .
    .
    // 1000 lines of functions and logic
    public void increaseAge(int years){
        age+=years;
    }
    
    public void doLogic(){
        //some logic
    }
    .
    .
    .
}
```

I don't know exactly how much memory will occupy a instance of this class, but let's say that the variables occupy `10 bytes` and the 1000 lines of functions occupy `1 kb` to put a sample amount.

If you have 100 instances of that class, the 100 times repeated variables should occupy `10*100 bytes` but what happens with the functions? will you have `1*100 kb` memory occupied for these functions? Or will the compiler do something to avoid that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I don't know exactly how much memory will occupy a instance of this class, but let's say that the variables occupy 10 bytes and the 1000 lines of functions occupy 1 kb to put a sample amount.

An instance of this class will occupy 10 bytes in this scenario.  (That's not actually possible, as objects have headers of various fixed sizes ranging from 4 to 12 bytes depending on JVM settings, and even then they're rounded up to a multiple of 8 bytes, but the point is that you only pay for the variables of the class.)

There is only one copy of the implementations of the functions for a given class stored in memory.

Comment: So, having 100 instances, the implementantions of the functions will occupy only the same amount than if it was only 1 instance?

Comment: Yes.  That follows from what I said.